# interfaces and object deserialization

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I have an interface which defines a class to be serializable to a byte array.

```
public interface IByteSerializable
{
    byte[] GetBytes();
}
```

The natural partner to this is a deserialize method, which I want to return an object that implements `IByteSerializable`.

I'm stuggling with how to design such an interface.

This doesn't seem to make sense:

```
public interface IByteSerializable
{
    byte[] GetBytes();
    IByteSerializable GetObject(byte[] bytes);
}
```

Because the implementation of `GetObject()` can't be `static` and it doesn't make sense to use a dummy `IByteSerializable` object just to call the `GetObject()` method to deserialize the *actual* object I'm after.

It also doesn't seem to make sense to do this:

```
public interface IByteSerializableFactory
{
    IByteSerializable GetObject(byte[] bytes);
}
```

A Factory class could solve the problem, but this feels like it will result in class explosion.  Also, the details of how a given `IByteSerializable` subclass are serialized then deserialized are co-dependent, so it makes sense to keep them in the same place, and not in two different classes. Obviously, the exact process required to deserialize a given `IByteSerializable` object depends entirely on how that object's `GetBytes()` method was written.

Is there a common design or pattern I can use to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of different opinions on interfaces, classes, and patterns when it comes to your question. My *personal* preference would be implementing an interface with a byte[] property and an abstract class with a virtual method (*or even losing the interface altogether, which might not be an option for you and does not play well with DI and unit testing*):

```
public interface IByteSerializable
{
    byte[] SerializableByteObject { get; }
}

public abstract class ByteSerializable : IByteSerializable
{
    public byte[] SerializableByteObject { get; }
    protected virtual byte[] GetBytes() {
        return SerializableByteObject;
    }
    public abstract IByteSerializable GetObject();
    //{    // You can make this method virtual and use Impl method:
           // GetObjectImpl(SerializableByteObject);
    //}
    protected internal IByteSerializable GetObjectImpl(byte[] bytes) {
        // If you need a default implementation (GetObject() should be protected virtual then)
        // return IByteSerializable...;
    }
}
```

I want to stress that interfaces VS abstract classes is an endless discussion. If you can do stuff without implementing interfaces and use just abstract classes - I would strongly recommend doing so.

**Update 3/18/17**: to reply to a comment (defining behavior is the purpose of an interface) and explain how I see it adding the explanation below.

In this scenario, the "behavior" we are defining is "An object should be convertible into a byte array. Conversion result should be convertible back into the same object." So we're actually defining behavior for an object and for a byte array (because after an object was deserialized - it's no longer the same object, it's just a byte array).

From my perspective, that's pure factory pattern scenario.

```
// Let's define an interface for our serializable type of objects factory
public interface IByteSerializableFactory<T>
{
     T CreateFromBytes(byte[] objectDataToUse);
     byte[] CovertToBytes(T objectToConvert);
}

// Interface for any class that needs a serialization factory
// This is not even necessary, but I like it to enforce people to implement simple methods that reference the factory.

public interface IByteSerializable<T>
{
    IByteSerializableFactory<T> GetFactory();
}

// Now a moment comes for us to have this kind of class. We need to build a factory first (because our interface requires a GetFactory() implementation. We can lose the IByteSerializable interface altogether, but then we lose a way to let people know which factory should be used.

public class SomeBaseClassSerializationFactory : IByteSerializableFactory<SomeBaseClass>
{
    public SomeBaseClass CreateFromBytes(byte[] objectDataToUse) { //...
        return new SomeClass();
    }
    public byte[] CovertToBytes(SomeBaseClass objectToConvert) { //...
        return new byte[1];
    }
}

// We have a factory, let's implement a class.

public abstract class SomeBaseClass : IByteSerializable<SomeBaseClass>
{
    public virtual IByteSerializableFactory<SomeBaseClass> GetFactory() { 
        return new SomeBaseClassSerializationFactory();                                             
    }
}

public class SomeClass : SomeBaseClass {
    // Now we're independent. Our derived classes do not need to implement anything.
    // If the way the derived class is serialized is different - we simply override the method
}
```

**Update 2 3/18/17**: to reply to a comment under a different answer (generic implementation with simple use of interface).

Unfortunately, there will be no clean way to do it. There is a dirty (my personal opinion: *"BAD BAD BAD!"*) way by using some cheating, defining classes that define serialization methods and using reflection to return correct type. The example below will require a lot of custom logic in the serialization method for using correct fields with different types:

```
// You define an enum with action and a dictionary with a collection of serialization methods.
public enum SerializationAction {
    ToBytes,
    ToObject    
}

// It can also be an enum, but it's easier to test with a collection of strings.
public static readonly string[] SerializationKindList = new string[] {
    "FirstKind",
    "SecondKind"
};

// This generic class can have an implementation of all the handlers. Additional switching can be done by type, or reflection can be used to find properties for different classes and construct different classes.
public class SerializationMethod {
    public object ProcessByKind (string kindToUse, SerializationAction action, object objectToProcess) {
        if (kindToUse == "FirstKind") {
            if (action == SerializationAction.ToBytes) {
                return new byte[1]; 
            }

            return new SomeClass(); // These would need to be your hard implementations. Not clean.
        } else {
            throw new NotImplementedException();    
        }
    }
}

// This struct type defines the serialization method and is required for the interface implementation
public struct ByteSerialization
{
    public string SerializationTypeName { get; private set; }
    public ByteSerialization(string kindToUse) {
        if (!SerializationKindList.Contains(kindToUse)) {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        SerializationTypeName = kindToUse;
    }
    public byte[] Deserialize(object objectToProcess) {
        var serializationMethod = new SerializationMethod();
        return (byte[])serializationMethod.ProcessByKind(this.SerializationTypeName, SerializationAction.ToBytes, objectToProcess);
    }
    public object Serialize(byte[] byteArrayToProcess) {
        var serializationMethod = new SerializationMethod();
        return serializationMethod.ProcessByKind(this.SerializationTypeName, SerializationAction.ToObject, byteArrayToProcess);
    }
}


// Interface for any class that needs to use generic serialization
public interface IByteSerializable
{
    ByteSerialization serializationType { get; }
}

// Creating extension methods for the interface to make the life easier
public static class IByteSerializableExtensions {
    public static byte[] DeserializeObjectIntoBytes(this IByteSerializable objectToProcess) {
        return objectToProcess.serializationType.Deserialize(objectToProcess);
    }
    public static void SerializeObjectFromBytes(this IByteSerializable objectToProcess, byte[] fromBytes) {
        var someObjectData = objectToProcess.serializationType.Serialize(fromBytes);
    }
}


// Abstract base class implementation with static readonly field.
// Only downside - there is no way to enforce the config of this field in the constructor from the interface.
// There also no way to make sure this field always gets set for other implementations of IByteSerializable
public abstract class SomeBaseClass : IByteSerializable
{
    private static readonly ByteSerialization _serializationType = new ByteSerialization("FirstKind");

    public ByteSerialization serializationType { get { return _serializationType; } }
}

public class SomeClass : SomeBaseClass {

}


// And here's how one would use it. You will need to create a new object of the class before serializing from bytes.
var someClass = new SomeClass();
var bytes = someClass.DeserializeObjectIntoBytes();
var someClass2 = new SomeClass();
var byteArray = new byte[1];
someClass2.SerializeObjectFromBytes(byteArray);
```

Comment: Thanks Phil.  I understand that you're stating you opinion here, but for my own learning - why do you suggest avoiding interfaces when possible?

Comment: @khargoosh Simply because interfaces are overused today. People are using them without really understanding what for. An interface is a contract, like a request to promise that certain things will be implemented - there is no need (I'm not talking about dependency injection right now) to implement a contract if one does not expect multiple implementations by different developers - interfaces will make stuff overly complicated.

Abstract classes though give one an ability to do almost the same thing and define default implementations (virtual methods).

Comment: I get what you're saying Phil, and thanks for your help it's greatly appreciated.  Looking at this specific case, don't you think that an `interface` makes more sense than an `abstract` class?  We're really defining behavior here, rather than defining *what an object is*.  Many different types of classes could find a valid use implementing an `IByteSerializable` interface - but they might also be more well defined as subtypes of a base classes that differ wildly.  Isn't this the very purpose of an interface?

Comment: @khargoosh,
You are correct, behavior definition is the very purpose of the interface. Let's simply say it in normal language: "I want an object to be serializable into a byte array. After serialization I want this byte array to be serializable back into the original object."
The behavior is defined for different objects: for your class and for a byte array. So the only behavior your class has: it's convertible to a byte array. If you have many classes that need to be built from a byte array: a factory pattern should be used instead.

Comment: Thanks for the update - I see where you're going with this, the `Factory` class is responsible for both serializing and deserializing the object.  Unfortunately this means I'll need a separate `Factory` class which implements `IByteSerializableFactory` for every class that implements `IByteSerializable` but maybe this is the best of the available choices.

Comment: @khargoosh Correct with one correction: you will need the factory for every BASE class. You are not obligated to implement the factory for children. Your factory can use a shared method that is used by all or half of your factories for different classes. If you share methods your overhead will be 6 lines per base class (and all the logic in the shared method, you can even switch based on Type parameter (if typeof(xxx)), it's especially easy with C# 7. 6 lines per class - almost unlimited flexibility and test-ability.

Comment: @khargoosh I've added another update to show a way that addresses your concern regarding CodingYoshi's answer. I still think it's not clean to do it the way I've done in the 3rd version of the solution.

Comment: Thanks Phil - honestly I can see the benefit in the Factory design pattern and it's how I'm going to proceed.  One question though - your `IByteSerializable` interface contains a method signature for the `GetFactory()` method.  Does this mean that I need an instance of my `IByteSerializable` object to get a reference to an `IByteSerializableFactory`, to then deserialize yet a different object?  This seems very roundabout.  Is that typical?

Comment: @khargoosh Correct, it seems roundabout and yes, you will need an instance of an object. Unfortunately, this is the only way to enforce factories for each class. Imagine: you have two arrays of bytes. One was serialized from "Car" object, another one was serialized from "Hamburger" object. How would the compiler know the "destination" object type? Only if we first get an instance of the object and use the CreateFromBytes from factory for that particular type.

To make the code cleaner it's typical to create extension methods which can set the properties in the first instance of an object.

Answer (score 2):

Use a generic interface and each implementation can close the generic and return the closed type. It is upto the implementation to decide what type to return.

```
public interface ICustomSerializable<T> where T : class
{
    byte[] GetBytes();
    T Deserialize(byte[]);
}

public class Foo : ICustomSerializable<Foo>
{
    public byte[] GetBytes() {} 
    public Foo Deserialize(byte[]){} 
} 

public class Bar : ICustomSerializable<Bar>
{
    public byte[] GetBytes() {} 
    public Bar Deserialize(byte[]){} 
}
```

If you have classes which do serialization in a common way then:

```
public abstract class Something
{
    public byte[] GetBytes() { //common code } 
} 

public class SomethingConcrete : Something, ICustomSerializable<SomethingConcrete>
{
    public SomethingConcrete Deserialize(byte[]){} 
}
```

Comment: Thanks CodingYoshi - I like the idea of using Generics to define a return type on the `Deserialize()` method.  Do you have any thoughts on how best to implement that interface method in an actual class - in a way that makes sense?  My original question still follows: a Factory class would result in class explosion; can't implement a static interface method; and deriving from `Something` just to implement *this behavior* or functionality doesn't seem to be a good design practice!  In your final example above, I would need an instance of `SomethingConcrete` to deserialize a different object.